# mySQL can't get results with zero occurrences to show with left outer join

Tags: mysql, left-join

Im breaking my head with this little query so hopefully someone can tell me what is wrong with it. I need to group orders by same month and year as well as order status. So I have different table with which matches a number let's say 4 to an order status in text (let's say DELIVERED). I am trying get mySQL to tell me out of each Month/Year how many orders it had in every given status (even if that number is zero). Up to this point I receive the right answer except for the months/year that have zero occurences. So I only see for example: 05/205 | DELIVERED | 45, but if there is for example zero "PENDING" orders for 05/25 I do not see  05/2015  | PENDING | 0 and that is what i'm looking for. Thanks a bunch guys

```
select order_statuses.status, order_statuses.status_text,
Month(str_to_date(orders.order_date, '%d/%c/%y')) as Good_Month, 
Year(str_to_date(orders.order_date, '%d/%c/%y')) as Good_Year, 
CONCAT(Month(str_to_date(orders.order_date, '%d/%c/%y')), "/",Year(str_to_date(orders.order_date, '%d/%c/%y'))) as The_Date
from order_statuses
left outer join orders
on order_statuses.`status` = orders.order_status
where orders.admin_comments like '%moveit.ca%' 
group by Good_Year, Good_Month, order_statuses.`status`
```

Comment: try to select with "FULL OUTER JOIN" or "CROSS JOIN".. or provide us table structure so we can understand what you are looking for. Ty..

Comment: Thanks Luca, I have the table structure and will be happy to show it to you but how can I paste it here without taking over the whole screen? Its pretty large. Thanks my friend

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/